# Log user input/touches through Android emulator on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, user-input

Is there a way to log with timestamps what object/input control a user touches on the emulator? Something similar to logcat, but I just want the id or name of the object that the user touched and at exactly what time. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to do this within your own app? or system wide?

Comment: I'd say system wide, because I want it to log input on any app that is opened. I think I can log input within my own app, but I want a way without changing an app's source code.

Comment: I think you will have to modify the system in order to allow for that.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?